# To kill or remove an Indestructible

Tags: magic-the-gathering, mtg-indestructible

Will the following cards kill something with "indestructible"?:

- [Swords to plowshares](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bSwords%20to%20plowshares%5d)
- [Terror](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bTerror%5d)
- [Wrath of God](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bWrath%20of%20God%5d)

Answer (score 9):

Indestructible means the permanent cannot be **destroyed.** Something would be destroyed if something says to destroy it, or if it takes lethal damage (e.g. a 3/3 takes 3 damage, or is dealt damage by something with deathtouch).

Terror and Wrath of God don't do anything to it. An indestructible creature isn't regenerating from destruction, it just isn't destroyed in the first place.

The common ways we remove an indestructible permanent are:

- Put it into any other zone:

  - Exile it. **This means [Swords to Plowshares](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bSwords%20to%20Plowshares%5d) works.**
  - Return it to its owner's hand (known as "bouncing" it): [Drag Under](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bDrag%20Under%5d), [Peel from Reality](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bPeel%20from%20Reality%5d), [and others](https://scryfall.com/search?q=o%3A%2Freturn.*to.*owner.*hand%2F).
  - Put it back into its owner's library (known as "tucking" it): [Condemn](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bCondemn%5d), [Chronostutter](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bChronostutter%5d), [and others](https://scryfall.com/search?q=o%3A%2Fput+.*into+.*+owner%27s.*library%2F+-o%3A%22shuffle+%7E%22).
- Make its controller sacrifice it.
- If it's a creature, reduce its toughness below 0, such as with [Tragic Slip](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bTragic%20Slip%5d).

There are some oddball other methods, such as making it a non-issue ([Song of the Dryads](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bSong%20of%20the%20Dryads%5d)) or unable to participate meaningfully ([Claustrophobia](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bClaustrophobia%5d), [Arrest](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bArrest%5d)), or making it [lose its abilities](https://scryfall.com/search?q=o%3Atarget+o%3A%2Flose.*abilities%2F) ([Snakeform](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bSnakeform%5d), [Gift of Tusks](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bGift%20of%20Tusks%5d)), or [just lose indestructible specifically](https://scryfall.com/search?q=o%3A%2Flose.*indestructible%2F).

Comment: There's also the option of using something like Claustraphobia or Arrest (similar to the aforementioned Song of the Dryads): you're not removing it, per se, but you're making it unusable.

Comment: @JohnDoe Thanks for bringing that up, I'd forgotten about that category. :)

Comment: you may want to add that the old keyword bury also means destroy.

Comment: @NeilMeyer It also sometimes meant sacrifice, so it's a bit messier than that. I'd rather not go there & just stick with recent rules concepts; all the cards here have errata anyway.

Comment: You can also gain control of it ;)